# Input string until Enter is pressed by using BIOS interrupt x86

Tags: x86, assembly

I've tried to allow user to input character from keyboard until they press Enter. However, when the 6th key is pressed, there is an error. Like I can write "hello" but it's impossible to write "hello1".

```
push dx
push bx
push dx
mov bx, dx
inputBuffer:
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16
    cmp al, 13
    je exit
    mov [bx], al
    inc bx
    jmp inputBuffer
exit:
;Print string
    mov byte ptr [bx], 0
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov bx, dx
    jmp printString
printString:
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, 0
    je endString
    int 0x10
    inc bx
    jmp printString
endString:
    ret
```

Comment: You're writing into `[bx]` but didn't show what that's pointing to.

Comment: What does "impossible" mean, what happens if you try to enter "hello1"?

Comment: @ecm if the character is a number, the program terminates. If the character is a letter, there is an announcement "not supported yet. refer to the list of supported interrupts."

Comment: @interjay I think mov bx, dx means bx stores the address of dx?

Comment: No, it copies the value of dx to bx. But the initial value would need to be set somewhere before this bit of code, and point to large-enough memory.  I'm assuming you didn't write this code?

Comment: @interjay thank you, it works now. I've just learnt this language in a rush so there are many things that I don't understand precisely